# Str_replace with subject passed by reference

Tags: php, string, str-replace

Given the following example:

```
public function replaceMyText($search, $replace, &$content)
{
    $newContent = str_replace($search, $replace, $content, $count = 1)
    $content = $newContent;
}
```

Can this cause a `Warning` that only variables can be passed by reference? If so, I can't fully understand why.

Should I assigned the `$content` to another variable before passing it to the `str_replace` function?

Comment: Did you try it?  Did it generate a warning?

Comment: Yes, it does... and I don't understand why. I tried the code, not the solution I proposed since I didn't understand the "why"

Comment: How are you calling this? Are you just passing a raw string as the third argument?

Comment: The error is coming from `$count = 1`. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Now I'm confused again. You say you're getting a warning, but this should either throw a fatal error if you're calling `replaceMyText` with a raw string, or a notice if it's the call to `str_replace` that's the problem. I'm not sure how you'd see a warning. Which are you seeing?

Comment: @iainn It's a `notice`, not a warning. Haven't paid enough attention to Rollbar. (Sorry). And yes, I am calling `replaceMyText` where the 3rd param is a string.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. If you're not using the `$count` parameter then just remove it from the function call entirely.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function replaceMyText($search, $replace, &$content)
{
    $newContent = str_replace($search, $replace, $content, $count = 1);
    $content = $newContent;
}

replaceMyText("123", "456", "123456");
```

using this function without variable will get a fatal error

```
Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in /usercode/file.php on line 8
```

because

> No other expressions should be passed by reference, as the result is undefined.

from http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

you just can using by this

```
$a = "123456";
replaceMyText("123", "456", $a);
echo $a;
```

Sorry for my bad english. I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Please try this code :

```
function replaceMyText($search, $replace, $content)
{
    $newContent = str_replace($search, $replace, $content,$count=1);
    return $newContent;
}

$searchValue = "test";
$replaceWith = "magic trick";
$actualContent = "This is a test.";

$replaced = replaceMyText($searchValue,$replaceWith,$actualContent);

echo $replaced;
```

Comment: I did check that link, and this example http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#108196 states exactly my solution as "working", unless I missed something.

Comment: @LostCoder Assigning a variable at the same time as passing it to a function did work in older versions of PHP, but was always a bad idea. I'm not sure which version was being used when that example was written, but it definitely isn't good practice.